# Applying a filter to subsequences of a sequence using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, collections

If I have a `List<MyType>` as so, with each line representing an item in the collection:

```
{{ Id = 1, Year = 2010 },
{ Id = 1, Year = 2009 },
{ Id = 1, Year = 2008 },
{ Id = 2, Year = 2010 },
{ Id = 2, Year = 2009 },
{ Id = 2, Year = 2008 }}
```

I wish to retrieve a collection from this collection of the most recent item for each Id. What will the Linq for this look like?

Desired output:

```
{{ Id = 1, Year = 2010 },
{ Id = 2, Year = 2010 }}
```

I have a naiive implementation using a second list variable and a foreach loop, but it's inefficient.

```
//naiive implementation "p-code"
//...
var mostRecentItems = new List<MyType>();    
var ids = collection.Select(i => i.Id).Distinct();
foreach(var id in ids)
{
  mostRecentItems.Add(collection.Where(i => i.Id == id).OrderByDescending().First);
}

return mostRecentItems;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most simply:

```
var mostRecentById = from item in list
                     group item by item.Id into g
                     select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Year).First();
```

Comment: Thanks. TBH, I haven't got my head quite around GroupBy. If anyone knows of a simple explanation online please post.

Comment: @Ben: This groups together everything with the same ID, then sorts each group by year, then takes the first value - i.e. the one with the highest year.

Comment: @Jon - is the "group" conceptually analogous to a temporary table? Clarification: does the grouping result in a sequence of subsequences matching the "by" upon which a subquery can be executed?

Comment: @Ben: Yes - each group has a Key property (the Id in this case) but is also a subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

Group by id, then select the first item in each group ordered in a descending fashion.

```
 var mostRecentItems = collection.GroupBy( c => c.Id )
                                 .Select( g => g.OrderByDescending( i => i.Year ).First() );
```

Answer (score 0):

or more simply still:

```
var result = list
                .GroupBy(i => i.Id)
                .Select(g => new {Id = g.Key, Year = g.Max(y => y.Year)});
```